# NuGet setup for code analyzers not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, roslyn-code-analysis, nuget-spec

I am working on setting up an internal NuGet package for code analyzers used by my team with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  I kept it simple by creating a new folder and used the "nuget spec" command to create the nuspec file.

My nuspec file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Test.CodeAnalysis</id>
    <version>1.0.0.5</version>
    <authors>Tom Atwood</authors>
    <owners>Tom Atwood</owners>
    <licenseUrl>LICENSEURL</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>PROJECTURL</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>ICONURL</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Code analysis analyzers used at my company.</description>
    <releaseNotes>No release notes available.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>COPYRIGHT MESSAGE HERE</copyright>
    <tags>code analysis</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer" version="[1.0.0.8]" />
      <dependency id="codecracker.CSharp" version="[1.0.0]" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" version="[1.1.0]" />
      <dependency id="RefactoringEssentials" version="[4.2.0]" />
      <dependency id="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" version="[1.16.0]" />
      <dependency id="StyleCop.Analyzers" version="[1.0.0]" />
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.51" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.52" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.61" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework="native0.0" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.51" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.52" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.61" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework="native0.0" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net40\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net45\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net451\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net452\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net46\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="\build\net461\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net40\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net45\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net451\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net452\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net46\" />
    <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" target = "\content\net461\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net40\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net45\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net451\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net452\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net46\" />
    <file src="stylecop.json" target = "\content\net461\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net40\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net45\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net451\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net452\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net46\" />
    <file src="install.ps1" target="\tools\net461\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net40\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net45\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net451\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net452\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net46\" />
    <file src="uninstall.ps1" target="\tools\net461\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The issues I have had are as follows:

1. Even though the stylecop.json file gets added to the target project as desired, the props file is not properly setting up the file.  For stylecop.json, this would mean having the following setting in the csproj file for the stylecop.json file to be active and recognized:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <AdditionalFiles include="stylecop.json"
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   Currently, instead of "AdditionalFiles", it gets setup as "None".
2. Even though the ruleset file is being loaded into the project, the project's properties do not enable code analysis on build, and the default "Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules" is set for the ruleset file instead of the imported file.

For both of the above items, the props file is setup as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>CodeAnalysis.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="stylecop.json"/>
    <CodeAnalysisDictionary Include="CodeAnalysis.Dictionary.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Please note the install.ps1 and uninstall.ps1 are in default configuration at the moment and are not handling any tasks.

There isn't a lot of detailed information about how to go about this correctly.  Are there specific issues I am executing incorrectly?

Comment: you going to have to use PowerShell to do these task above in your install.ps1

Comment: I was worried you were going to say that Josh...

Comment: Any luck finding how to set BuildAction = AdditionalFiles via install.ps1? This analyzer sdk project template has a screwy nuget.